# How to get comma separated values from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have the following mysqli query, and I want to implode the array that's outputted into a `(1,2,3,4)` type format.

Here's the query and the asoc array code:

```
$user_categories = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT sub_cat FROM subscriptions WHERE sub_user_id = '$user_id'");

$category_ids = mysqli_fetch_all($user_categories,MYSQLI_NUM);

print_r($category_ids);

$category_ids = implode(", ",$category_ids);
```

I then get the following output, and I can't seem to isolate the values...

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 8 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) 
)
```

Apologies if I'm missing something really obvious here. I've been trying to fix this for a while, and due to my lack of PHP experience, I'm not 100% sure what to search for.

I've also tried a simple implode using the results of the `$user_categories` query, following the instructions of other StackExchange answers I've seen on the topic, but got nothing (code below):

```
$user_categories = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT sub_cat FROM subscriptions WHERE sub_user_id = '$user_id'");

$category_ids = implode(", ",$user_categories);

echo $category_ids;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect as output, can you please write an example?

Comment: It says in the first sentence: `(1,2,3,4)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$category_ids` is an array of arrays (rows), so you can't just implode it. You need to fetch the first value from each row and implode that.

#### PHP 5.5+ solution:

Using [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$category_ids = implode(', ', array_column($category_ids, 0));

echo $category_ids;
```

Output:

> 5, 8, 4, 2

#### PHP 5.3+ solution:

Subtitute [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$category_ids = implode(', ', array_map(function ($row) { return $row[0]; }, $category_ids));

echo $category_ids;
```

Output:

> 5, 8, 4, 2

Comment: Thank you, you're a life saver! 
Accepted and +1 for clear 5.3 + 5.5 answers :)

Comment: Sometimes I find answers who do not have the deserved upvotes.
Nice solutions Shira

Answer (score 2):

`$category_ids` that you get from `mysqli_fetch_all` is array of arrays and the desired result cannot be retrieved just by passing it to implode. However, this should do the job:

```
$category_ids = mysqli_fetch_all($user_categories,MYSQLI_NUM);

$category_ids_imploded = implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
  return $entry['0'];
}, $category_ids));
```

Alternatively, in case you're using PHP 5.5 or higher, you can make it a bit less messy by using `array_column`:

```
$category_ids_imploded = implode(', ', array_column($category_ids, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mysql solution

```
$sql = "SELECT group_concat(sub_cat) FROM subscriptions WHERE sub_user_id = '$user_id'"
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$category_ids = mysqli_fetch_row($user_categories)[0];
```

## PDO solution (preferred)

```
$sql = "SELECT group_concat(sub_cat) FROM subscriptions WHERE sub_user_id = ?"
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$user_id]);
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$category_ids = implode(",", $array);
```